# Как написать этот код GApp Script в виде цикла?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть таблица со списком всех имеющихся таблиц(названия этих таблиц могут изменяться). Чтобы держать список названий актуальными я написал скрипт, который берет со столбца "C" id таблиц, открывает таблицу по этому id, берет название и вставляет в столбец "В". Проблема в том, что список постоянно пополняется и менять скрипт не удобно, поэтому я хотел бы написать его в виде цикла

```
function GetSpreadSheetsName33() {
  var SpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Тут ID Таблицы').getSheetByName('Accesses');
  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B2").setValue(SheetName);

  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B3").setValue(SheetName);

  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B4").setValue(SheetName); 

  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B5").setValue(SheetName);    

  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C6").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B6").setValue(SheetName);  

  var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("C7").getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B7").setValue(SheetName);  
  }
```

Методом "тыка" получилось это, только оно не работает

```
function GetSpreadSheetsName() {
var i = 2;
var SpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Тут ID таблицы').getSheetByName('Accesses');
  while (SpreadSheets.getRange("C"+i).getValue().lenght>1)
  {
  i++;
    var Data = SpreadSheets.getRange("С"+i).getValue();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Data).getName();
  SpreadSheets.getRange("B"+i).setValue(SheetName);
  }
    }
```

[Этот вопрос на Toster Ru](https://toster.ru/q/503219)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройти все строки начиная со второй (как я понял из вашего скрипта) и записать имя таблицы в столбец B:

```
function GetSpreadSheetsName() {
  // Если скрипт внутри таблицы      
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  // Если скрипт запускается не из таблицы, где находится Ваш список
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ВАШ ID")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ИМЯ ЛИСТА НА КОТОРОМ ВАЩ СПИСОК")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

  for(var i = 2; i<=lastRow;i++){
    if(sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()){
      sheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()).getName())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо